# How to find reason of memory leak when using browser notification?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I need to show notification via browser extension. The code below is reproduce example outside the extension. Can you explan why memory usage doesn't decrease after notification close?

1. Allow StackOverflow show notification in browser settings
2. Open browser task manager (Shift + Esc)
3. Run the code below in dev console
4. Look at memory usage of the tab.

```
let count = 0
let intervalId = null

Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
    intervalId = setInterval(showNotification, 10e3)

});

function showNotification() {
    count += 1
    if (count == 5) {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
        console.log('finish')
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let n = new Notification("My Great Song", {
            icon: 'https://i.redd.it/v05doii2jwp31.jpg?t=' + Date.now(),
            requireInteraction: true,
        });

        let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            n.close()
            n = null
            clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        }, 5e3)
    }
}
```

In my case after finish code memory usage up from 90 to 200mb and never decrease.

I am purposely choice icon with large size in order to do show possible memory leak. With small size happen the same, just need to more time and iteration.

If return to the browser extension context, happen the same. My service worker never close because it need to listen websocket. After some notifications memory usage increase forever.

In memory dev tools all JS VM instance less than 4-6mb. So almost all memory spent to notification that already closed.

```
// content.ts
async function onNofityAboutStream(stream: NotificationStream) {
    let streamInfo = (await Client.getStreamInfo(stream.channelPath)).body
    BackgroundClient.showNotification(stream.channelPath, {
        title: streamInfo.user.displayName,
        message: streamInfo.title,
        iconUrl: streamInfo.user.avatarUrl,
        type: 'basic',
        requireInteraction: true,
    })
}
```

```
// background.ts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageReceived)

function onMessageReceived(message: Message<any>, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender) {
    if (message.type == RuntimeMessageType.ShowNotificationEvent) {
        onCreateNotification(message.data)
    }
}

async function onCreateNotification(data: any) {
    chrome.notifications.create(data.notificationId, data.notificationOptions)
    const notificationId = data.notificationId
    const seconds = await settingLiveStorage.instance.autoCloseNotificationAboutStreamSeconds.value()
    if (seconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => chrome.notifications.clear(notificationId), seconds * 1000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research I came to the conslusion that the Notification class is cached in some way.

[image]

[image]

I said in some way because it is not a conventional way. Javascript uses a Garbage Collector to dispose unused objects from memory and, as a result, the Notification class objects are somehow still in use. I reached this conclusion by using the memory profiler of my web browser and searching the `Notification` class in my heap allocated objects and the result is shown above. I tried `delete`, to destroy the object, but the `delete` keyword will not destroy the object, but it will destroy the reference `n`. As the result of the previously mentioned fact, the conclusion is that the `Notification` class instances created are held in memory by the runtime because they are still in use, and any attempt to free them will destroy only the variable that references them.

The only viable way of deleting the cache is to reload the page.
So on page reload, the memory will be freed and in order to control the page notification system between page reloads you can use some persistent memory cache to implement the logic that will control the notification system between reloads. To add a value in the page reload  persistent memory cache `localStorage`, use  `localStorage.getItem('name');` to retrieve the value of an item,
use the `localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');` to add an item, and `localStorage.removeItem('name');` to remove an item.